# In JavaScript, must bound parameters be in the anonymous function parameters?

Tags: javascript

Consider the code below, which works fine. It is the outcome of some debugging.  It appears to work because I have inlcluded selectedRowNum not only in bind but it seems I am also required to include selectedRowNum as a parameter to the anonymous callback that is run by .end

Does this make sense? If I bind a variable, must I also include it as a param to the function I am binding it to?

```
for (var i = selectedRows.length; i--;) {
    var selectedRowNum = selectedRows[i];
    console.log('outer selectedRowNum');
    console.log(selectedRowNum);
    var url = urlbase + '/' + this.state.data[selectedRowNum].id;
    request
          .del(url)
          .end(function(selectedRowNum, err, res) {
            var data = this.state.data.slice();
            data.splice(selectedRowNum, 1);
            this.setState({data: data});
            this.forceUpdate();
            }.bind(this, selectedRowNum));
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to.

The args values passed to the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will be prepended to the called functions param list, so you need to receive it in the target function as arguments.

A simple example will be

```js
function x(p1, p2, p3) {
  console.log(p1, p2, p3)
}

var fn = x.bind(window, 1);

fn(2, 3);
fn('a', 'b');
```

where we are passing an additional param 1 to the bind and when the binded function is called we are passing `2` and 3, now when we receive it in the method we need to have 3 parameters there.

Comment: But what about "this"? I am also binding "this" but it is not in the function params.

Comment: @DukeDougal `this` will be the execution context for the target function... ie `this` inside the target function will refer to the object you have passed here

Answer (score 0):

How else do you expect to reference the bound value that you're trying to pass in?

`function(selectedRowNum, err, res) {` here `selectedRowNum` is simply a reference to the first argument that's passed in.

Well, technically the answer is no you don't need to. You could not list it as an argument, and refer to it as `arguments[0]`

Comment: I disagree with this. If you were to have the function header ``function (err, res) {`` that would be incorrect since ``err`` would then refer to ``selectedRowNum`` and so on. So, yes you do need to, if you want your code to semantically make sense.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `must bound parameters be in the anonymous function parameters` technically, no. What you said is true, but he's not even using `err` or `res` at all. You could just put no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are not absolutely required to be in the anonymous function declaration because you can access arguments via the `arguments` object as in `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`.

But it is best to declare them as named arguments because it makes your code easier to read and write.  If you don't declare them as named arguments in the anonymous declaration, then there is no symbolic name by which to refer to them and you are forced to use the `arguments` object to access them.

This is an important aspect of Javascript.  Declaring named function arguments in a function declaration (whether anonymous or not) just gives you name by which you can refer to that specific argument.  Since having a symbolic name is an important part of creating readable code, it is generally considered a good practice to follow.

When you use `.bind()` with arguments in addition to just the first argument, you are prepending more arguments to the actual function call.  This will shift any other arguments later in the argument list.  In order to access the correct argument, the anonymous function declaration must use the variables from the right spot in the argument list.  If you don't include the extra variables that are added via `.bind()`, then your other arguments will be out of position and will have the wrong values.